# Vagrant configuration

Tags: ruby, vagrant

I was wondering where the default commands of vagrant are defined. 
How does vagrant know what to do when you type in "vagrant up" where is this defined?

I want to make vagrant echo something when you type the command vagrant up for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

vagrant reads the [Vagrantfile](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/vagrantfile/) when you execute the `vagrant` command

If you want to echo something when you run the command you'll need to put in this file which is roughly a ruby script

example :

```
# -*- mode: ruby -*-
# vi: set ft=ruby :

Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|
  config.vm.box = "xxxxx"
  .... your config

  p "put your text here"
  p "#{Dir.pwd}"

  ARGV.each do|a|
    puts "Argument: #{a}"
  end
  p ARGV[0]
and
```

Comment: Nice, but how about vagrant destroy for example? or is this a whole different question?

Comment: the same Vagrantfile is read when each vagrant command is run .. thats also why I put the example of `ARGV.each` because thats a trick if you need to "echo" only on specific action